# How do I make a popover appear over a button inside a collection view protype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, popover

I created a UpcomingCell.h and .m for the cell. In the button's tap method i tried this

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
//    cameraSystemMenu =   [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraSystemMenuViewController"];

    UIView *anchor = sender;
    UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
               initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                             inView:anchor.superview
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

and I also tried this

```
self.popoverContent = [[PopOverViewController alloc]init];


UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];

[popoverView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];



self.popoverContent.view = popoverView;

self.popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 300);

UIPopoverController *contactPopover =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.popoverContent];

[contactPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.remindButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES ];

[contactPopover setDelegate:self];
```

and countless other popover examples on stackoverflow and I cant get it to work.

Both examples crashes. The first one crashes on

the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. This will be an exception in a future release

Comment: try using a NSLog(@"%@",NSStringfromCGRect(anchor.frame)) or NSLog(@"%@",NSStringfromCGRect(anchor.superview.frame)) to see what's going on; I'm not sure, but maybe you should cast to UIView in UIView *anchor = (UIView *) sender

Comment: The second one crashes because an UIPopoverController needs to be a property or an instance variable, otherwise it will be deallocated on the end of the method, because the View that's showing it will not retain it

Comment: Thanks the second one work for me when I made it a property. If you put that in an answer then il mark it as right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one crashes because an UIPopoverController needs to be a property or an instance variable, otherwise it will be deallocated on the end of the method, because the View that's showing it will not retain it